# No fbml tags working on page

Tags: php, facebook

I have integrated fb connect & fb like in my [site](http://naturalkart.com/index.php) .My site is in zencart.

Everything was working properly until yesterday.But not no fbml tags are working on my page , if I add iframe like tag then it works.I have checked it debugger console , as per it I did add meta tags , but its also not helping.
Before it was working without meta tags also , now it wont work with meta tags .

Please give me some suitable solution.

Answer (score 1):

From http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/

"FBML has been deprecated. Starting June 1, 2012 FBML apps will no longer work as all FBML endpoints will be removed. If you are building a new application on Facebook.com, please implement your application using HTML, JavaScript and CSS. You can use our JavaScript SDK and Social Plugins to embedded many of the same social features available in FBML."

Comment: Hey thnx for your quick response , but I have copied fb:like from there social plugin tool.If I use there iframe tag then if works.